# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firebase' in 'C:

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I'm getting this error in my vuejs webApp, hope some one tell me how to solve it:

```
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?
type=script&index=0!./src/components/Envio.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firebase' in 
'C:\Users\#####\Desktop\#####\src\components'
@ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?
type=script&index=0!./src/components/Envio.vue 17:0-32
 @ ./src/components/Envio.vue
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-
 server ./src/main.js
```

this is the script in my vue file:

```
<script>

import { db } from './firebase'

    export default {
      data: {
    mensaje: null,
 ... }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have installed `firebase` via a node package manager using `npm` command. If so, the following import statement should fix the problem.

```
import { db } from 'firebase'
```